# save image to a buffer

Tags: c, image, buffer

I have standalone bunch of images (.png) and would like to push it a buffer. I was wondering, how to construct a buffer for images and push them up to buffer. Eventually retrieve them later as bunch. i'm trying to implement in C. can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want to put the complete file, as is, in the buffer? Or do you want to parse the file and put just the actual image data in the buffer? If the latter, see e.g. [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).

Comment: When you read image by libpng, you save data to allocated memory buffer which size you can know by png meta information. What do you mean by "buffer for images"?

Comment: oh. okay! I actually thought of dumping the whole image to buffer. I'm  new to buffers concept and hence wondering how to construct the buffer, so that it can store images in a sequence. LAter I could read them back. Currently, I'm not worried about how its done (with parse/ with out). so, I'll definately explore libpng if it could help me. Thank you!

Comment: @Eddy_Em' okay! 'buffer for images,I mean some kind of pre-occupied array of sequential memory blocks, where each block can store image content. so, when some one tries to reads images, i can enforce synchronization rules to avoid deadlock.

Comment: I don't understand you. Do you mean storing images in shared memory? You store each image in memory like linear array of pixels, string by string. But if you wanna be able to share that memory buffer with different applications, you can store it in shared memory.

Comment: yes! it could be sequential array of pixels in shared memory. so that other applications can read it (parse it back). can libpng do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to use OpenCV in your application for processing these images? If yes then you can use OpenCV to load image into Cv::Mat objects. You can load then as array of Mat objects

Comment: I haven't used it anytime. I'll give it a try with that.